# Is there a way antiSMASH can be used to screen a large number of genomes just for one type of biosynthetic gene cluster?

Tags: genome, gene, bash, sequence, data-mining

When we use [antismash](https://antismash.secondarymetabolites.org/#!/start) command with the genome sequence file as follows:

```
antismash GCA_002095535.1_ASM209553v1_genomic.gbff
```

it screens the genome for all the possible biosynthetic gene clusters (BGCs).

Is there a way the tool can be directed to screen for only one specific type of BGC (for example, terpene)?

Comment: Hi @snap_v I think the answer to the question is about parsing the output. If you present the raw output for a typical search have a go at a bit of code and wrap it up as a new question - I think you'll get a solution.